# Could anyone explain cmp and sel in scandir for me?

Tags: c

```
int musl_scandir(const char *path, struct dirent ***res,
   int (*sel)(const struct dirent *),
   int (*cmp)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **)) {

    DIR *d = opendir(path);
    struct dirent *de;
    struct dirent **names = NULL;
    struct dirent **tmp;
    size_t cnt = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    if (!d) {
        return -1;
    }

    while ((de = readdir(d))) {
        if (sel && !sel(de)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (cnt >= len) {
            len = 2 * len + 1;
            if (len > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(*names)) {
                break;
            }
            tmp = realloc(names, len * sizeof(*names));
            if (!tmp) {
                break;
            }
            names = tmp;
        }
        names[cnt] = malloc(de->d_reclen);
        if (!names[cnt]) {
            break;
        }
        memcpy(names[cnt++], de, de->d_reclen);
    }

    closedir(d);

    if (errno) {
        if (names) {
            while (cnt-- > 0) {
                free(names[cnt]);
            }
        }
        free(names);
        return -1;
    }
    if (cmp) {
        qsort(names, cnt, sizeof *names, 
            (int (*)(const void *, const void *))cmp);
    }
    *res = names;
    return cnt;
}
```

I know scandir is for creating a directory listing (array of strings of the contents of a directory), but I really want to understand how this works. 
If anyone could go over the general framework of the code above and how this works (line by line), I would greatly appreciate it. 
Also, please help me understand what sel and cmp are used for. And why  does cmp not have any parameters when it's being used... what are the parameters for those?

Comment: `len = 2 * len + 1;
            if (len > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(*names)) {` is iffy code.  Better to   test `len` before increasing it.  `if (len > (SIZE_MAX / sizeof(*names) - 1)/2)`.

Answer (score 1):

`sel` is treated as a selector if given, when it returns 0 the directory is skipped.

```
   if (sel && !sel(de)) {
```

`cmp` is passed to quick sort as the comparison function to compare two entries and determine which one should go first.

```
if (cmp) {
    qsort(names, cnt, sizeof *names, 
        (int (*)(const void *, const void *))cmp);
}
```

Both are function pointers, `sel` is passed the parameter as I noted above while `cmp` is passed along to `qsort()` which will internally invoke it with appropriate parameters.

**Update**: Comparison functions, `cmp` above, are generally defined to return an integer with the following meaning:

- negative means `a < b`, generally `-1` but do not rely on the magnitude just the sign.
- `0` means `a == b`
- positive means `a > b`, generally `-1` but do not rely on the magnitude just the sign.

The selector function, `sel` above, returns an integer - really a Boolean `true`/`false` - but this looks like old C which did not have `bool` type. So, `false` becomes `0` while any other integer becomes `true`.

Comment: what else can sel return other than 0? I don't understand what the integer it returns means

Comment: Updated my answer to better explain the return types of `sel` and `cmp`.